# Spock datatable parameter changes its value during test

Tags: testing, groovy, datatable, spock

It seems like one of the parameter in my data table changes its value during the test, and I have no clue why. I can't debug the test with IntelliJ 15

Simplified:

```
given:
def listOfMDOProxies = Stub(List) {
    get(_) >> Stub(IMDOProxy) {
          get() >> {
               savedSearchStub(bluSubSearchType, mockData)           
          }
    }
}

when: call to test method...

where:
mockData | bluSubSearchType
false    | null

private SavedSearchWO savedSearchStub(BluSubSearchType bluSubSearchType, boolean mockData) {
getSearchData() >> {
                if (mockData) {
                    Stub(ProfSearchData) {
                    }
                } else {
                    null
                }
            }
}
```

my problem is, that in the 'savedSearchStub' method the parameter 'mockData' should always be false, but at some point it changes to true. And mockData is only assigned in the data table in the where block.

Ayn ideas?

Comment: It's hard to help right now. Could you please edit your answer and provide a full example?

Comment: Sorry, the full example has too much boilerplate, it won't help you. My question is just about the 'mockData', and this parameter/value is only assigned in the datatable.